# FakeBasicAuth and AuthzSVNAccessFile: how to refer to users?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, ssl-certificate

When using Apache2 with client certificates and FakeBasicAuth, how do I refer to users in the `AuthzSVNAccessFile`? The usernames have funny characters, like `/CN=Damon Wischik`, and authz doesn't like the `=` character in usernames.

My Apache configuration has the lines

```
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth
```

This means that the user provides a client certificate, Apache takes the subject line from the certificate e.g. `/CN=Damon Wischik`, and uses that as the username and "password" as the password. I've added an `htpasswd` entry for this user, and he can log on happily.

Now I want to add fine-grained access control to the repository, and I can't work out how to refer to this username in the `AuthzSVNAccessFile`. I started off with

```
[/]
* = r
```

and the user was able to read the contents of the repository. I tried writing

```
[/]
* =
"/CN=Damon Wischik" = r
```

and the user gets "Access forbidden", and the Apache error log says

```
[date] [error] [client ip] Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: The character 'D' in rule '"/CN' is not allowed in authz rules
[date] [error] [client ip] Access denied: '/CN=Damon Wischik' GET foo:/
```

What's the correct way to escape these funny characters in usernames, in the authz file?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but generally speaking you'd escape a character by using a backslash before the character.

Comment: If I try username /CN\=Damon Wischik, I get the error message: "The character 'D' in rule '/CN\\' is not allowed in authz rules"

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to Stefan Sperling on the subversion-users mailing list for the answer.) RTFM! From the [red bean book chapter 6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html),

> Subversion 1.5 brought several useful features to the access file
>   syntax—username aliases, authentication class tokens, and a new rule
>   exclusion mechanism—all of which further simplify the maintenance of
>   the access file.

Here is how to use aliases in this particular case.

```
[aliases]
djw = /CN=Damon Wischik

[/]
* = 
&djw = r
```